# How to Show Caps lock, Number Lock in right corner?

Tags: wingpanel, settings, keyboard

I'm new to Elementary OS. I was running Debian with Gnome2.
My laptop does not have LED indicators for caps lock or any lock for that matter. Is there an applet for Elementary OS to display this?

"Num Lock and Caps lock indicator in the Icon Bar?"

If there is not, Is there any way to make one?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own issue. This should be standard with every Elementry OS installation.

Execute the following command in a terminal window. It installs the indicator for the caps lock and numeric lock keys.

```
sudo apt install indicator-keylock
```

Comment: This does not work in Elementary OS 5 Juno